# Image upload with preview using Ajax ascyfileuploader

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to upload image on server side folder using ajaxtoolkit ascyfileuploader but I want to preview that image and want to change name of that image before uploading it on server side.
Can anybody suggest me how to perform this operation?
thank you

Comment: You may upload the image on the server with a temporary name (for example generated with guid) and then open a webform with an image tag that reference the image uploaded

Comment: thank you for response..
can you send me code because I am beginner in asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before previewing image upload temporarily at server. If user want to upload it just [rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161917/changing-name-of-uploaded-images) the image name otherwise delete/remove it from server.